# Pause Stop watch timer in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to NSTimer in iPhone. i made a stop watch. now i want to pause time in between
and also want to do resume pause. my code is given bellow.

- How can I pause time?
- How can i resume from where the time is stop?

Start Time:

```
startDate = [[NSDate date]retain];
stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

Stop Time:

```
[stopWatchTimer invalidate];
stopWatchTimer = nil;
[self updateTimer];
```

Update Time:

```
(void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use NSTimeInterval instead of timer. I have a functional code to pause and stop the timer.

```
@interface PerformBenchmarksViewController () {

    int currMinute;
    int currSecond;
    int currHour;
    int mins;
    NSDate *startDate;
    NSTimeInterval secondsAlreadyRun;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    running = false;
}

- (IBAction)StartTimer:(id)sender {

    if(running == false) {

        //start timer
        running = true;
        startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        [sender setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self updateTime];
    }
    else {
        //pause timer
        secondsAlreadyRun += [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
        startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        running = false;
    }
}

- (void)updateTime {

    if(running == false) return;

    //calculate elapsed time
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval elapsed = secondsAlreadyRun + currentTime - startTime;

    // extract out the minutes, seconds, and hours of seconds from elapsed time:
    int hours = (int)(mins / 60.0);
    elapsed -= hours * 60;
    mins = (int)(elapsed / 60.0);
    elapsed -= mins * 60;
    int secs = (int) (elapsed);

    //update our lable using the format of 00:00:00
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u", hours, mins, secs];

    //call uptadeTime again after 1 second
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1];
}
```

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: Useful and easy to understand, solves my problem, thanks for sharing! However, when extracting out the hours from elapsed time, I think it should be:
 `int hours = (int)(elapsed / 3600.00);
elapsed -= hours * 3600;`
Otherwise it goes wrong after 60 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I created some extra variables to help keep track on the elapsed time:

1. `BOOL watchStart;`
2. `NSTimeInterval pauseTimeInterval;`

I set watchStart = NO and pauseTimeInterval = 0.0.

I used watchStart to check if its a start or pause condition (for my `IBAction`), and in `updateTimer`, I set the `timeInterval` to `pauseTimeInterval`.

The crucial part of the code is:

```
_startDate = [_startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(_pauseTimeInterval))]
```

That line will add the extra `timeInterval` to the `startDate` for calculation of the time that was paused. It's kind of like "stepping back" in time to add in the interval that was previously recorded.

```
-(void) updateTimer {

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];    
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.S"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

    NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    _stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
    _pauseTimeInterval = timeInterval;

}



-(IBAction)btnStartPause:(id)sender {

    if(_watchStart == NO) {
        _watchStart = YES;
        _startDate = [NSDate date];
        _startDate = [_startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(_pauseTimeInterval))];
        _stopWatchTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else {
        _watchStart = NO;
        [_stopWatchTime invalidate];
        _stopWatchTime = nil;
        [self updateTimer];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimer` does not have pause or resume methods. You can make 2 types of timers, one that implements only once and the second, that repeats. Example:

Creates a timer that will enter callback myMethod each second.

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
    target:self 
    selector:@selector(myMethod:) 
    userInfo:nil 
    repeats:YES];
```

You probably will choose this one for your purpose where in your class you should maintain some

`BOOL pausevariable` and in the callback myMethod do the following:

```
 - (void) myMethod:(NSTimer *) aTimer
{
     if (!pause) {
       // do something
       // update your GUI
     }
}
```

where you update pause in your code. To stop the timer and release memory, call

```
 [myTimer invalidate];
```

hope this helped.

Comment: i know that NSTimer doesn't have pause and resume method. but i don't have any idea about how to pause, so is there any logic to pause timer. by the way thanks for your compliment.

Comment: then why did you say "I am new to NSTimer in iPhone. i made a stop watch. now i want to pause time in between and also want to do resume pause". :)

Answer (score 0):

Small correction for the above example:

```
_startDate = [_startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(_pauseTimeInterval))];
```

Add retain @ the end :

```
_startDate = [[_startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(_pauseTimeInterval))]retain];
```

This will make things better :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)startStopwatch
{

//initialize the timer HUD
[self setSeconds:second];
// [self.hud.stopwatch setSeconds:_secondsLeft];

//schedule a new timer
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(tick:)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];
}

-(void)pause{

 [_timer invalidate];
}

-(void)resume {

 [_timer isValid];

}
```

using this code we can pause and resume the timer

Answer (score 0):

Friends i was successful in implementing pause and resume function to iOs timer app, the code is as follows

```
- (IBAction)pauseT:(id)sender {
se = sec;
mi = min;
ho = hour;
[timer invalidate];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)resumeT:(id)sender {
sec = se;
min = mi;
hour = ho;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

Hope this works for you guys..