# Timer: start-pause-resume-stop not working the way it should in ios

Tags: ios

I have a `timer` in my application.There are *buttons to start and stop*,one button for pause and resume.

ex-

- **start**- starts from 0sec;
- **pause**- pause at 20sec;
- **resume**- i wait for 10 sec then press resume, timer starts from 30sec;

code for pause timer

```
    (IBAction)pauseTimer:sender
    {
       [self.timer invalidate];
       self.timer = nil;
    }
```

> But i want it to start from 21sec how to do that??

Help me please.Thanks in  advance

Comment: To allow others to help you, you should show some of your code.

Comment: Give us some code and be more specific. Are you using time interval or NSCalendar?

Comment: I'm using time interval.

Comment: You must invalidate the counter, look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849644/pause-stop-watch-timer-in-iphone

Comment: And add some code, be more specific or people will mark you down

Comment: Your question is not specific, and search before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic outline of a class to achieve this.  The idea is that the timer fires every second and timer is only accumlated (into `_timerValue`) if the paused flag (`_paused`) is `NO`.

TimerClass.h:

```
@interface TimerClass : NSObject {
    NSTimer *_timer;
    BOOL _paused;
    NSInteger _timerValue;
}

@end
```

TimerClass.m:

```
@implementation TimerClass

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    NSAssert(!_timer, @"Already started");
    _timerValue = 0;
    _paused = NO;
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(tick:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)pauseTimer:(id)sender {
    _paused = YES;
}

- (IBAction)resumeTimer:(id)sender {
    _paused = NO;
}

- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (!_paused)
        _timerValue++;
}

@end
```

Comment: Pause n resume are working correctly,thanks.

Comment: @user3168158 So why have you removed the *accepted answer* from it then?

Comment: dint observe.I thought its not accepted.If green mark is there then its accepted right? sorry....

Comment: @user3168158 Yes.  You seemed to have flipped-flopped between two different answers for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope that you need a `Instance Variable(NSInteger) to keep track on it` .

For ex:

```
NSNumber intForKeepTrackOnTime;
    - (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender
    {
        if (_timer == nil)
        {

     _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(_timerFired)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        }
    }

    - (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender
    {  // Invalidate the timer and also nil the Value of Tracking Variable.
        intForKeepTrackOnTime = 0;
        if (_timer != nil)
        {
            [_timer invalidate];
            _timer = nil;
        }
    }

  - (IBAction)pauseTimer:(id)sender
    {  // Invalidate the timer only

        if (_timer != nil)
        {
            [_timer invalidate];
            _timer = nil;
        }
    }
    - (IBAction)resumeTimer:(id)sender
    {  //Start the timer only.
       if (_timer == nil)
        {

     _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(_timerFired)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        }
    }
    - (void)_timerFired
    { //Keep Track on
       intForKeepTrackOnTime++;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, global variable?  I think you mean instance variable.

Comment: Yup, Sorry to misType...